Upgraded Ubuntu to 22.04 and cannot login
I am fairly new to using Ubuntu, but I tried to upgrade it from 20.04 to 22.04 on my machine and now I’m stuck at a black screen after rebooting. The error messages read something like:
Nvidia-gpu: timeout error Ucsi_ccg: i2c transfer failed  Ucsi_ccg: ucsi_ccg_init failed 
I have tried everything I can to try to get to my login screen and access my desktop/workstation, and I cannot. Please provide any and all advice.
When I try to reboot my computer, I get the following after choosing "Ubuntu" on the main start menu:
[2.303434] nvidia-gpu 0000: 02:00:3: i2c timeout error e000000 [2.303454] ucsi_ccg 0-0000: i2c_transfer failed -110
[2.303456] 0-0000: ucsci_ccg 0-0000: ucsi_ccg_init failed - 110, /dev/nvme0n1p7: clean, 400025/7331040 files, 14864192/29296096 blocks.

I have tried many things, such as the instructions listed here: Black screen on boot after upgrade ubuntu server from 22.04 to 22.04.01, as well as rebooting multiple times, tried to fix broken dependencies.

Please edit the question and put in the exact error message. Also please add to the question everything you have tried and the messages or errors you got.

When I try to reboot my computer, I get the following after choosing "Ubuntu" on the main start menu:

I am now trying to install a new driver to see if that was the problem.

A new driver for what? Also never put question info in a comment edit the question and add the info. Please edit the question and ADD the info.

Gotcha, will update the question. It was suggested by a colleague to try installing a different nvidia driver in the case that my driver was not compatible/did not upgrade with my Ubuntu update
